# Return response from AngularJS factory

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jax-rs, response

I am trying to return a response from server.

Take the example of adding a car to the server, my AngularJS factory is the following:

```
 app.factory('CarServices', function ($resource) {
 return $resource('/ws/cars', {}, {
    query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
    create: { method: 'POST' },
    delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'} }
 })
});
```

Then, In my CarController I have this function:

```
// callback for ng-click 'addCar':
$scope.addCar= function () {
    $scope.car = { "plate": "778899", "brand": "Ferrari" };
    CarServices.create($scope.car).$promise.then(function() {
        // If success, show success message
    }, function(error) {
        // If error, show message from server
    });
}
```

I am using Java with RESTful WebServices and this is my WebService:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addCar(JsonCar jc) {

 Car car = new Car(jc.getPlate(), jc.getBrand());
 if(car.getByPlate()) {
  return Response.ok().build();
 } else {

return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
            .entity("Car does not exist on database").build();
}
}
```

So, I wan't that in case of error on the controller, show the message "Car does not exist on database" but instead of that I am getting this error (console.log(error)):

> json.parse unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the json data

Thank you.

Comment: What is your desired return? Are you returning a promise

Comment: Hi, I added some information.
My desired return is the error message so I can say to the user what went wrong. In my case, I want to check if a car exists in database and if not, return an error message that can be displayed on browser. Assuming a post request with the object car

Comment: What do you mean by "inject $response"? Can you show us the code that uses the `appServices` factory?

Comment: I added an example using a car object so you can understand better what I want and also added the function that calls the appServices (now called "CarServices". By inject $response I mean: how can I get the full response so I can access that error message that says "Car does not exist on database" ?